# How to stop jmeter during runtime based on coditions?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-plugins

I wanted to stop jmeter if my conditional logic is false,suppose if one of my conditions gets failed then i need to stop immediately all my threads(jmeter) during run time,so that is there any way stop it running time through code not manually(not thru action to be taken after a sampler error)

Thanks,
in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 options for you:

1. If your condition can be expressed in If Controller, then use standard [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) Component to stop test
2. If you want to stop test when response time or error rate increases some threshod, then use custom [AutoStop](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/AutoStop) Component